mysql 2823 records only showing
CREATE TABLE sales_data_new (
    `ORDERNUMBER` DECIMAL(38, 0) NOT NULL, 
    `QUANTITYORDERED` DECIMAL(38, 0) NOT NULL, 
    `PRICEEACH` DECIMAL(38, 2) NOT NULL, 
    `ORDERLINENUMBER` DECIMAL(38, 0) NOT NULL, 
    `SALES` DECIMAL(38, 2) NOT NULL, 
    `ORDERDATE` VARCHAR(30), 
    `STATUS` VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL, 
    `QTR_ID` DECIMAL(38, 0) NOT NULL, 
    `MONTH_ID` DECIMAL(38, 0) NOT NULL, 
    `YEAR_ID` DECIMAL(38, 0) NOT NULL, 
    `PRODUCTLINE` VARCHAR(16) NOT NULL, 
    `MSRP` DECIMAL(38, 0) NOT NULL, 
    `PRODUCTCODE` VARCHAR(9) NOT NULL, 
    `CUSTOMERNAME` VARCHAR(34) NOT NULL, 
    `PHONE` VARCHAR(17) NOT NULL, 
    `ADDRESSLINE1` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL, 
    `ADDRESSLINE2` VARCHAR(50), 
    `CITY` VARCHAR(14) NOT NULL, 
    `STATE` VARCHAR(13), 
    `POSTALCODE` VARCHAR(9), 
    `COUNTRY` VARCHAR(11) NOT NULL, 
    `TERRITORY` VARCHAR(5), 
    `CONTACTLASTNAME` VARCHAR(11) NOT NULL, 
    `CONTACTFIRSTNAME` VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL, 
    `DEALSIZE` VARCHAR(6) NOT NULL
);


load data  infile '/Users/thispc/Downloads/sales_data_sample_cleaned.csv'
into table sales_data_new
fields terminated by ','
enclosed by '"'
lines terminated by '\n'
ignore 1 rows;

Everything is fine till now
select count(*) from sales_data_new;
#output 2823
select * from sales_data_new;
after this i got the records
When i downloaded the file then in excel the count is 65443
#how
SET SESSION SQL_MODE = ' ';
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'secure_file_priv';
SET NAMES 'utf8mb4';
SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES = 0;
SHOW WARNINGS;
tried something like this but didn't find nothing

Do all the records match the delimiter you've chosen? Any chance the last record contains the rest of the file but is getting truncated? This is where I would start looking.
